# When are the stack exchange accounts synced?

Tags: support, user-accounts, stackexchange

The information seen on a users profile about the accounts - is there a certain interval for sync between the sites of stackexchange?

Or when are latest changes synced to the other sites?

For example if I earn some reputation on `tex.stackexchange.com` when is this information available on my profile on e.g. `stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: never mind from `tex.stackexchange.com` to `meta.tex.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: I think syncing with the [accounts tab](http://stackexchange.com/users/1389840/bertram-nudelbach?tab=accounts) is pretty much immediate. Rep sync from tex.SX to meta can take a while (maybe an hour). What else needs to be synced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anywhere between 5 minutes and a day, depending on what's being synced.

I believe most things sync on an hourly basis.